# How to set amazon ami's hadoop configuration by using java code

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I want set this configuration `textinputformat.record.delimiter=;` to the hadoop.

Right now i use the following code to run pig script on ami. Anyone knows how to set this configuration by using the following code?

Code:

```
StepConfig installPig = new StepConfig()
.withName("Install Pig")
.withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW.name())
.withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newInstallPigStep());

// [Configure pig script][1]

String[] scriptArgs = new String[] { "-p", input, "-p", output };
StepConfig runPigLatinScript = new StepConfig()
.withName("Run Pig Script")             .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CANCEL_AND_WAIT.name())
.withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newRunPigScriptStep("s3://pig/script.pig", scriptArgs));

// Configure JobFlow [R1][2], [R3][3]
//
//

RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
.withName(jobFlowName)
.withSteps(installPig, runPigLatinScript)
.withLogUri(logUri)
.withAmiVersion("2.3.2")
.withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
            .withEc2KeyName(this.ec2KeyName)
            .withInstanceCount(this.count)
            .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
            .withMasterInstanceType(this.masterType)
            .withSlaveInstanceType(this.slaveType));
// Run JobFlow
RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = this.amazonEmrClient.runJobFlow(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create `BootstrapActionConfig` and add it to the `RunJobFlowRequest` being created, which would then add custom hadoop configuration to the cluster.

Here is the complete code I wrote for you after editing the code [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html) :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.BootstrapActionConfig;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.JobFlowInstancesConfig;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.RunJobFlowRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.RunJobFlowResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.ScriptBootstrapActionConfig;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.StepConfig;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.util.StepFactory;

/**
 * 
 * @author amar
 * 
 */
public class RunEMRJobFlow {

    private static final String CONFIG_HADOOP_BOOTSTRAP_ACTION = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String accessKey = "";
        String secretKey = "";
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

        StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();

        StepConfig enabledebugging = new StepConfig().withName("Enable debugging")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW").withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep());

        StepConfig installHive = new StepConfig().withName("Install Hive").withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newInstallHiveStep());
        List<String> setMappersArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
        setMappersArgs.add("-s");
        setMappersArgs.add("textinputformat.record.delimiter=;");

        BootstrapActionConfig mappersBootstrapConfig = createBootstrapAction("Set Hadoop Config",
                CONFIG_HADOOP_BOOTSTRAP_ACTION, setMappersArgs);

        RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withBootstrapActions(mappersBootstrapConfig)
                .withName("Hive Interactive")
                .withSteps(enabledebugging, installHive)
                .withLogUri("s3://myawsbucket/")
                .withInstances(
                        new JobFlowInstancesConfig().withEc2KeyName("keypair").withHadoopVersion("0.20")
                                .withInstanceCount(5).withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
                                .withMasterInstanceType("m1.small").withSlaveInstanceType("m1.small"));

        RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
    }

    private static BootstrapActionConfig createBootstrapAction(String bootstrapName, String bootstrapPath,
            List<String> args) {

        ScriptBootstrapActionConfig bootstrapScriptConfig = new ScriptBootstrapActionConfig();
        bootstrapScriptConfig.setPath(bootstrapPath);

        if (args != null) {
            bootstrapScriptConfig.setArgs(args);
        }

        BootstrapActionConfig bootstrapConfig = new BootstrapActionConfig();
        bootstrapConfig.setName(bootstrapName);
        bootstrapConfig.setScriptBootstrapAction(bootstrapScriptConfig);

        return bootstrapConfig;
    }

}
```